# How to set the default value to LocalDateTime in @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have controller that is accepting the request with `LocalDateTime` as query parameter

```
@GetMapping("test")
public void test(@RequestParam(value = "date", required = false, defaultValue = ?) LocalDateTime date) {
    System.out.println("The date is : "+date);

}
```

I know we can set the default value for `String` and `Integer` using `defaultValue` in `@RequestParam`, but how to set the default value for `LocalDateTime` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [spring expression language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) to set the default value for any object

```
@GetMapping("test")
public void test(@RequestParam(value = "date", required = false, defaultValue = "#{T(java.time.LocalDateTime).now()}") LocalDateTime date) {
    System.out.println("The date is : " + date);

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to format that default value, too?

Comment: If you format then it will be string and not `LocalDateTime` @payne

Comment: I see. So there is no way to do something like `defaultValue = "#{T(java.time.LocalDateTime).now().format(T(java.time.DateTimeFormatter).ofPattern('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')}"` for a `LocalDateTime`. I've been wondering because I want to use `spring.mvc.format.date-time: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` in my `application.yml` properties file. I guess I should keep that `LocalDateTime.now()` as default and ensure I format it in the logic before processing further: like that I get the default to be formatted like I want, and still get validation when a value is actually provided ? It's kind of hackish.